# difference between signin and signup with facebook, what should the app do on signup?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I don't seem to get the purpose of the signup with facebook, it appears to be the same as the signin. My question is: what does the app supposed to get and save when the user is signingup to my app with facebook?

I am wondering why isn't there any guide, insights from facebook docs on the Signup process?

Comment: Can you add more details? Are you talking about the FB SDK? Which one?

Comment: Yes, the facebook sdk.

Answer (score 1):

**Sign In Facebook**---  this will popup a FB login screen, after login the app will authorize your permission to access some of your Facebook profile details.

**Sign Up Facebook**---  this is popup a new signup screen , where u have to register your details and and an Facebook account is created so that you can authorize the app to access your details.

Answer (score 0):

Signin -> Existing user to login into Facebook

SignUp -> New user, he needs to create a new Facebook Account.

Comment: create new facebook account? I am talking about signing up to my app within the facebook app. If the user has already a facebook account, what are the data that should be retrieved and saved in my own server?

Comment: Oh... in that case if user has set some security then a secret code may be sent by the fb. which needs to be entered first time. then you can save the login-email id+ pwd for future logins through your app. Which in turn will be sent to fb.

Comment: When I first signup on Pinterest with my facebook account, they simply move to the facebook app and then get back to Pinterest. Nothing is entered by me, even the password. So I am wondering, what is happening during the signup process, how can I request that secret code you are referring to from FB ?

Comment: I said if security is enabled then fb sends a secret code. In normal case it wont. Check the fb settings for more